# undetected-chromedriver not loading a page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

Trying to load a page ("https://www.bet365.gr/#/IP/B1") with undetected chromedriver the page stuck on loading.

I tried multi options none worked.

Also tried selenium stealth.

```
#httpswww.bet365.gr#IPB1
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
import mysql.connector
import requests
from random_user_agent.user_agent import UserAgent
from random_user_agent.params import SoftwareName, OperatingSystem
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

options = uc.ChromeOptions() 
options.headless = False

driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, options=options)
arr=[]
while True:
    url="https://www.bet365.gr/#/IP/B1"
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: There is no value in telling us you tried some stuff without stating exactly what you tried.  It is useless information, and you may just get suggestions for solutions already tried.  That effort duplication will not make you popular.  Moreover if you show what you have tried, it may be possible to tell you why they did not work, which would be instructive.